# Guidance for retrieving number of page views using Google Analytics API

Tags: java, javascript, grails, google-analytics, analytics

An answer of the question [Best grails implementation for tracking number of views (or unique visitors) for a web page ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906097/best-grails-implementation-for-tracking-number-of-views-or-unique-visitors-for)  was to use [Google Analytics API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/) for tracking and displaying the number of page views for some particular page on my website.

I liked the idea and had a look of the Google Analytics API but, at first view, it seems to me quite complicated and my needs are very basics (i.e. displaying number of people who have views some particular pages of my website).

So I'd like to know if there is any **tutorial** out there or if you can give me some guidance that shows **how to retrieve (and display) number of unique views for some of my web pages** using Google Analytics API (in Java or JavaScript) or even Feeds.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This page has an example of getting started and data using a DataQuery:

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/2.0/gdataJava.html#retrievingData

Then, this page:

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html

has a good tool to help building the query you need. My guess would be to use the pagePath dimension and the pageViews metric. That would give you the page views per url for a given date range.

cheers

Lee

Comment: Thank you veyr much. It is indeed a veyr good and quick start